# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function :When clicking kendo Action Sheet List buttons?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, uiactionsheet

i have a problem when i am trying to load a kendo action sheet control in my application.
My problem is when i try to click the list .it shows Undefined not a function.

Html:

```
 <ul id="actions">
                        <li><a href="#"  data-action="view">New Appointment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"  data-action="rename">View Info</a></li>

                    </ul>
```

JS:

```
 $("#actions").kendoMobileActionSheet({ type: "tablet" });

$("#kendogrid").on("click", "tr", function () {
    var CustomerID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#actions").data("kendoMobileActionSheet").open(this);
});
```

if i am clicking the grid it shows the kendo action sheet.which contains to links .When i try to click this link i get the error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data-action attribute of the action sheet items points to a JavaScript function which must be globally available. You should have functions "view" and "rename" defined in your page. If you don't you will get the "undefined is not a function" error.

Comment: And then one more suggestion...i cannot use the knockout attr binding here..how can i resolve this sir?